# Directive to complete with RandomAccessFile read

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http

I have a large data file and respond to GET requests with very small portions of that file as `Array[Byte]`

The directive is:

```
get {
  dataRepo.load(param).map(data =>
    complete(
      HttpResponse(
        entity = HttpEntity(myContentType, data),
        headers = List(gzipContentEncoding)
      )
    )
  ).getOrElse(complete(HttpResponse(status = StatusCodes.NoContent)))
}
```

Where `dataRepo.load` is a function along the lines of:

```
val pointers: Option[Long, Int] = calculateFilePointers(param)
pointers.map { case (index, length) =>
  val dataReader = new RandomAccessFile(dataFile, "r")
  dataReader.seek(index)
  val data = Array.ofDim[Byte](length)
  dataReader.readFully(data)
  data
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to pipe the RandomAccessFile read directly back in the response, rather than having to read it fully first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reading the data into a `Array[Byte]` you could create an `Iterator[Array[Byte]]` which reads chunks of the file at a time:

```
val dataReader = new RandomAccessFile(dataFile, 'r')

val chunkSize = 1024

Iterator
  .range(index, index + length, chunkSize)
  .map {  currentIndex =>
    val currentBytes = 
      Array.ofDim[Byte](Math.min(chunkSize, length - currentIndex))

    dataReader seek currentIndex
    dataReader readFully currentBytes

    currentBytes
  }
```

This iterator can now feed an akka `Source`:

```
val source : Source[Array[Byte], _] = 
  Source fromIterator (() => dataRepo.load(param))
```

Which can then feed an HttpEntity:

```
val byteStrSource : Source[ByteString, _] = source.map(ByteString.apply)

val httpEntity = HttpEntity(myContentType, byteStrSource)
```

Now each client will only use 1024 Bytes of memory at-a-time instead of the full length of your file read.  This will make your server much more efficient at handling multiple concurrent requests as well as allowing your `dataRepo.load` to return immediately with a lazy `Source` value instead of utilizing a `Future`.